# MySql Numbering the rows of query based on group by

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a table like this

```
id          name           city
-------------------------------
1            Ian           London
2            John          London
3            David         New York
4            Sylvia        Mumbai
5            Beryl         New York
6            Rashan        London
```

I would like to retrieve the data with a row numbering that is grouped on City. Like this.

```
name          city          count
-------------------------------
Ian           London          0
John          London          1
Rashan        London          2
Beryl         New York        0
David         New York        1
Sylvia        Mumbai          0
```

I have been trying with

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY name)-1
```

But the count is of all the items returned, where I would like to count the number of people in each city.

Comment: Your code should do what you want. Please show us your entire query.

Comment: `select name, city, row_number() over (partition by city order by name)-1 from people;` Works For Me™

Comment: @Mono . . . I think you just want `order by city, name` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should do what you want - however, you mention `group by`, which is irrelevant here. The query should just be:

```
select name, city, row_number() over(partition by city order by name) - 1 rn
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I realized that I had made a typo and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

To get the results that you specify:

```
select name, city, row_number() over (partition by city, order by name) as count
from t
order by count(*) over (partition by city) desc,  -- number of rows in city
         city,
         name;
```

You seem to want the cities ordered by the number of names in the city.